# jQuery ajax not working with ASP MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am using asp mvc and created a function in my controller:

```
public bool UsernameCheck(string name)
        {
            return true;
        }
```

Then i created a jQuery ajax function on my HTML page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#usernamebox").change(function (e) {
        $userval = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "usernamecheck",
            data: { name : $userval },
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "string",
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
                if (result) {
                    $("#usernameava").text("Available"); // HTML DOM replace
                }else {
                    $("#usernameava").text("Not available"); // HTML DOM replace
                }
            },
            error:function () {
                console.log("e");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

but when i typing the text in text box it return **Status Code: 200 OK** and return data is **True**.

**But I don't understand that why my  success function is not executing. It always execute error function.**

Please help me. I can't find what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Did you try putting a breakpoint to both your error and success functions and see what is coming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your action method is returning a boolean value. but in your ajax call, you mentioned the `datatype` you are expecting from server is `string` which is not a valid option for the dataType property.

You should remove

```
dataType: "string"
```

If no value is provided for this property, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response coming back from the server.

or you can specify `text` as the value which is a valid option.

```
dataType: "text"
```

Also, your method parameter name is `name`, so change accordingly in your javascript code

```
data: { name : $userval },
```

Also, It is a good idea to use the `Url.Action` helper method to generate the relative url to the action method. If your script is in a razor view, you can use this

```
url: "@Url.Action("usernamecheck","YourControllerNameHere")",
```

Comment: i just changes name but still same thing happening . i got the Status Code:200 OK and return data is True . but still error function executing

Comment: i just changed the both thing like you says . but still facing the same problem .  i got the Status Code:200 OK and return data is True . but still error function executing

Comment: did you removing the dataType:"string" ?

Comment: @Shuju no . give me one min .

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies within your dataType setting. It is expecting an unknown dataType that will make it automatically default to the error.

Try this instead: `dataType: "text",`

**EDIT**

The available data types are: `text`, `html`, `xml`, `json`, `jsonp`, and `script`.